# Split a concatenated field delimited by pipe

Tags: regex, groovy, split

I have a field whose value is a concatenated set of fields delimited by `|` (pipe),

Note:- **escape character is also a pipe**.

Given:
`AB|||1|BC||DE`

Required:
`["AB|","1","BC|DE"]`

How can I split the given string into an array or list without iterating character by character (i.e. using regex or any other method) to get what is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's an unused character you can substitute for the doubled-pipe you could do this:

```
groovy:000> s = "AB|||1|BC||DE"
===> AB|||1|BC||DE
groovy:000> Arrays.asList(s.replaceAll('\\|\\|', '@').split('\\|'))*.replaceAll(
'@', '|')
===> [AB|, 1, BC|DE]
```

Cleaned up with a magic char sequence and using tokenize it would look like:

```
pipeChars = 'ZZ' // or whatever
s.replaceAll('\\|\\|', pipeChars).tokenize('\\|')*.replaceAll(pipeChars, '|')
```

Of course this assumes that it's valid to go left-to-right across the string grouping the pipes into pairs, so each pair becomes a single pipe in the output, and the left-over pipes become the delimiters. When you start with something like

```
['AB|', '|1', 'BC|DE']
```

which gets encoded as

```
AB|||||1|BC||DE
```

then the whole encoding scheme falls apart, it's entirely unclear how to group the pairs of pipes in order to recover the original values. 'X|||||Y' could have been generated by  ['X|','|Y'] or ['X||', 'Y'] or ['X', '||Y'], there is no way to know which it was.

Comment: +1 though in my experience you should use some sort of magic sequence of chars rather than `@`. Even if there should be no @ symbols in your data, someone will always add an @

Comment: And you can use tokenize instead of split, and get rid of the Arrays.asList

Comment: This is good but what if the values are ["AB|","|1","BC|DE"]? It will be encoded as "AB|||||1|BC||DE". The result of the solution above will be ["AB||", "1","BC|DE"].   Is there any character that can't be found printed on a keyboard that can be used as delimeter?

Comment: @CodeAssasin: sure, you could pick some unicode character you think would be obscure enough, like Will's snowman ("\u2603" ?). But that doesn't change the core problem, which is that you can't distinguish the delimiter from the values.

Comment: Ok. So the best way to solve this is to use a delimeter that is the least likely to be part of the values. I think this is an old problem, any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the split('|') method - but from what you provided, it looks like you can also have the '|' character in the field value.  Any chance you can change the delimiter character to something that is not in the resulting values?

Comment: Basically that is the reason why I asked. Any delimeter can be a part of the resulting values.